# Loading a OneDrive document

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, windows-store, onedrive

I am working on a Windows Store app. I have a path to a OneDrive document. I try to open it using:

```
await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);
```

I know the file is present, as I can navigate to it (`C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\Example.txt`), but for some reason awaiting `GetFileFromPathAsync` always throws an exception. I am calling this code from a function which is called within my `MainPage` constructor, something like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    ...
    LoadFile("C:\\Users\\User\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Example.txt");
    ...
}

private async void LoadFile(string path)
{
    await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Just wrapped a try-catch statement around it; it says the exception is "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied." But, I'm not sure how this can be, or what I am missing. Is it because I'm not using the file picker? I read online that apps won't be approved if I hack the manifest's app capabilities to add the documents capability...so there is no standard way to save the last file path used and load it again on startup?

Comment: This answered my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478074/how-to-automatically-load-previously-used-files-on-windows-store-app-startup